# Custom Customer Grid page is not showing perfectly after clicking search button in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have made a custom customer grid for magento admin panel.

It shows perfectly but the problem is that when I click search button it returns page without any theme.

please look into snapshots and code.

[image]

after clicking search button, it shows this,

[image]

I have written following code to generate this.

[company]/[namespace]/Design/Block/Customer/Grid.php

```
<?php
```

class Company_Namespace_Block_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    //$this->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc');
    //         $this->setId('customerGrid');
    //         $this->setUseAjax(true);
    //         $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    //         $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addNameToSelect()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('billing_company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc');
    ;

    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('company');
    $this->setCollection($collection);

    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{
    $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ID'),
            'width'     => '50px',
            'index'     => 'entity_id',
            'type'  => 'number',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('company', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Company'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'billing_company'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('email', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Email'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'email'
    ));

    $groups = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/group_collection')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', array('gt'=> 0))
    ->load()
    ->toOptionHash();

    $this->addColumn('group', array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
            'width'     =>  '100',
            'index'     =>  'group_id',
            'type'      =>  'options',
            'options'   =>  $groups,
    ));

    $this->addColumn('Telephone', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Telephone'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'index'     => 'billing_telephone'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_postcode', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('ZIP'),
            'width'     => '90',
            'index'     => 'billing_postcode',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_country_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Country'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'country',
            'index'     => 'billing_country_id',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_region', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('State/Province'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'index'     => 'billing_region',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('customer_since', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Since'),
            'type'      => 'datetime',
            'align'     => 'center',
            'index'     => 'created_at',
            'gmtoffset' => true
    ));

    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $this->addColumn('website_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Website'),
                'align'     => 'center',
                'width'     => '80px',
                'type'      => 'options',
                'options'   => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getWebsiteOptionHash(true),
                'index'     => 'website_id',
        ));
    }

    $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                    'header'    =>  Mage::helper('customer')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '100',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'    => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                            array(
                                    'caption'   => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Edit'),
                                    'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                                    'field'     => 'id'

                            )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('customer')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('customer')->__('Excel XML'));
    return parent::_prepareColumns();
}
protected function _prepareMassaction()
{
    parent::_prepareMassaction();
    //      $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
    //      $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('customer');

    //      $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('delete', array(
    //              'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Delete'),
    //              'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massDelete'),
    //              'confirm'  => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Are you sure?')
    //      ));

    //      $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('newsletter_subscribe', array(
    //              'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Subscribe to Newsletter'),
    //              'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massSubscribe')
    //      ));

    //      $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('newsletter_unsubscribe', array(
    //              'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Unsubscribe from Newsletter'),
    //              'url'      => $this->getUrl('*/*/massUnsubscribe')
    //      ));

    //      $groups = $this->helper('customer')->getGroups()->toOptionArray();

    //      array_unshift($groups, array('label'=> '', 'value'=> ''));
    //      $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('assign_group', array(
    //              'label'        => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Assign a Customer Group'),
    //              'url'          => $this->getUrl('*/*/massAssignGroup'),
    //              'additional'   => array(
    //                      'visibility'    => array(
    //                              'name'     => 'group',
    //                              'type'     => 'select',
    //                              'class'    => 'required-entry',
    //                              'label'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Group'),
    //                              'values'   => $groups
    //                      )
    //              )
    //      ));

    //      return $this;
}
public function getGridUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=> true));
}

public function getRowUrl($row)
{
    return $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array('id'=>$row->getId()));
}
```

}

and

my config.xml

```
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <customer_grid>Company_Namespace_Block_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
                <!-- rewrite the customer grid -->

            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it 
Edited code for `__costruct` method

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
//  $this->addAttributeToSort('entity_id', 'desc');
    $this->setId('customerGrid');
    $this->setUseAjax(true);
    $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
    $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you commented out `$this->setUseAjax(true);` in the `__construct` method. Put it back.
You can do the same for `$this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);` but it's not mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @marius, 
only please wait logo keeps rotating like this

http://www.axertion.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/magento-category-loading.jpg

Image is different, only this loading image is shown.
It's not loading the page.